# Prevent Handler From Starting On Exploit

Tags: metasploit

I want to be able to start up my handler in the background, and then attack multiple targets without each exploit starting its own handler...

For instance, when I am attacking a target...

```
[*] Exploiting target 192.168.1.2
[*] Started reverse TCP handler on 192.168.1.1:4446
[*] 192.168.1.2:7001 - Sending handshake...
```

I don't want the reverse TCP handler started when I exploit, I want to use a background TCP handler to catch all of the incoming shells because when I execute this exploit, it completes but no session is created, then 10 minutes later, a session will be created for a previous target while attacking another target, so I just want to do a catch-all in the background, while I loop through my targets.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Run the listener as a job and set exit on session to false

```
set EXITONSESSION false
```

then

```
exploit -j
```

then view all active sessions with

```
sessions
```

and interact with specific session with

```
session -i n         # n being the number of the session
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multi/handler](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/multi/handler) to handle any incoming sessions coming your way. It can handle any reverse connections *(including pure netcat reverse connects)* and payload callbacks, if you define the payload before running the plugin.

```
msf > use exploit/multi/handler
msf > set ExitOnSession false
msf > set payload /the/payload/you/use
msf > run
```